# check if there are such functions that verify the following functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

**The statement of the problem**:  Determine if there are any functions $f : (1, \infty)\rightarrow (1, \infty)$ with the property:

$ x^{f(y)^x} $ = $ y^{f(x)^y}\text{for every }x, y > 1$

**My approach**: I first proved that it is an injective function. Then I logarithmized in the $x$ base and then in the $y$ base and I reached some equalities. From there, I tried to "guess" if there is any such function but I didn't find anything so I guess we have to prove that there is no such function.

Any and all proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The power scheme is ambiguous. Please use Mathjax.

Comment: it's x to the power of f(y) , and f(y) to the power of x . the same for the right side , it's y to the power of f(x) , and f(x) to the power of y .

Comment: After taking log on both sides substituting $y$ as $e$ , gives $f(x)$ right ?

Comment: @AAM there is $f(e)$ also, but it is just a constant

Comment: @DS the question has to provide such values, for example in the functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, the exact function can not be found without the value of $f(1)$ or any other value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is indeed no such function**

Suppose such $f : (1, \infty)\rightarrow(1, \infty)$ exists. Observe firstly that the dimensionality of the constraint on $f$ causes $f$ to be determined by its value at any one point in the following way. Let's consider, arbitrarily, $f(2)$. Let $f(2) = a$, then we have by the constraint for $y = 2$:

$$x^{(a^x)} = 2^{(f(x)^2)}$$
$$a^x \log_2 x = f(x)^2$$
$$f(x) = \sqrt{a^x \log_2 x}$$

Now we see if this holds up to scrutiny elsewhere along the constraint. Note the constraint is trivial if $x = y$, and of course it will hold for $y = 2$ (and by symmetry, $x = 2$) by design, so let's try, say $x = 4$ and $y = 8$. The constraint is then:
$$4^{\left(\sqrt{a^8 \log_2 8}\right)^4} = 8^{\left(\sqrt{a^4 \log_2 4}\right)^8}$$
$$4^{\left(\sqrt{3a^8}\right)^4} = 8^{\left(\sqrt{2a^4}\right)^8}$$
$$4^{(9a^{16})} = 8^{(16a^{16})}$$
$$9a^{16}\log_2 4 = 16a^{16}\log_2 8$$
$$18a^{16} = 48a^{16}$$

Clearly this has the sole solution $a = 0$. Yet, by supposition, $a$ is in the range of $f$, but this contradicts $f$ being into $(1, \infty)$, thus no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Thank you so much !